# Lookup Trigger Problem

Tags: trigger, triggercontext

Currently, ObjA have a field called Commit/Exclude which is a picklist.

When the field ObjA.Commit_Exclude__c == "Commit", update 
ObjA.CustomRelationship__r.ObjB'sField to be "Commit"

When the field ObjA.Commit_Exclude__c == "Exlude", update 
ObjA.CustomRelationship__r.ObjB'sField to be "Exclude"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this?

```
if(trigger.isAfter){                
    if(trigger.isUpdate){ 

        String excludeValue = 'Exclude';
        String commitValue = 'Commit';

        CustomRelationship__c[] updateCR = new CustomRelationship__c[]{};
        CustomRelationship__c crAux;

        for(ObjA__c a : Trigger.new){

            if(String.isNotBlank(CustomRelationship__c)){

                crAux = new CustomRelationship__c( Id = a.CustomRelationship__c);

                if(a.Commit_Exclude__c  == excludeValue){

                    crAux.Status__c = excludeValue;

                } else if(a.Commit_Exclude__c  == commitValue){

                    crAux.Status__c = commitValue;

                }

                updateCR.add(crAux);
            }    
        } 

        update updateCR;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this CustomRelationship__c ?? I have a field of custom relationship by the name of opportunity__c as Standard Opportunity which I need to populate one of its field.

Comment: my parent object api Name is CustomRelationship__c and the look-up field in the child object (ObjA__c) is CustomRelationship__c. if you tell me the name of your parent and child object and the lookup field in the child object i can rewrite my code